# Getting the observations in a rpart's node (i.e.: CART)

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I would like to inspect all the observations that reached some node in an rpart decision tree. For example, in the following code:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit

n= 81 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 81 17 absent (0.79012346 0.20987654)  
   2) Start>=8.5 62  6 absent (0.90322581 0.09677419)  
     4) Start>=14.5 29  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
     5) Start< 14.5 33  6 absent (0.81818182 0.18181818)  
      10) Age< 55 12  0 absent (1.00000000 0.00000000) *
      11) Age>=55 21  6 absent (0.71428571 0.28571429)  
        22) Age>=111 14  2 absent (0.85714286 0.14285714) *
        23) Age< 111 7  3 present (0.42857143 0.57142857) *
   3) Start< 8.5 19  8 present (0.42105263 0.57894737) *
```

I would like to see all the observations in node (5) (i.e.: the 33 observations for which Start>=8.5 & Start< 14.5). Obviously I could manually get to them. But I would like to have some function like (say) "get_node_date". For which I could just run get_node_date(5) - and get the relevant observations.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be no such function which enables an extraction of the observations from a specific node. I would solve it as follows: first determine which rule/s is/are used for the node you are insterested in. You can use `path.rpart` for it. Then you could apply the rule/s one after the other to extract the observations.

This approach as a function:

```
get_node_date <- function(tree = fit, node = 5){
  rule <- path.rpart(tree, node)
  rule_2 <- sapply(rule[[1]][-1], function(x) strsplit(x, '(?<=[><=])(?=[^><=])|(?<=[^><=])(?=[><=])', perl = TRUE))
  ind <- apply(do.call(cbind, lapply(rule_2, function(x) eval(call(x[2], kyphosis[,x[1]], as.numeric(x[3]))))), 1, all)
  kyphosis[ind,]
  }
```

For node 5 you get:

```
get_node_date()

 node number: 5 
   root
   Start>=8.5
   Start< 14.5
   Kyphosis Age Number Start
2    absent 158      3    14
10  present  59      6    12
11  present  82      5    14
14   absent   1      4    12
18   absent 175      5    13
20   absent  27      4     9
23  present  96      3    12
26   absent   9      5    13
28   absent 100      3    14
32   absent 125      2    11
33   absent 130      5    13
35   absent 140      5    11
37   absent   1      3     9
39   absent  20      6     9
40  present  91      5    12
42   absent  35      3    13
46  present 139      3    10
48   absent 131      5    13
50   absent 177      2    14
51   absent  68      5    10
57   absent   2      3    13
59   absent  51      7     9
60   absent 102      3    13
66   absent  17      4    10
68   absent 159      4    13
69   absent  18      4    11
71   absent 158      5    14
72   absent 127      4    12
74   absent 206      4    10
77  present 157      3    13
78   absent  26      7    13
79   absent 120      2    13
81   absent  36      4    13
```

Answer (score 2):

Terminal node assignments for training observations in rpart can be obtained from `$where`:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit$where
```

As a function:

```
get_node <- function(rpart.object=fit, data=kyphosis, node.number=5) {
  data[which(fit$where == node.number),]  
}
get_node()
```

This works for training observations only though, not for new observations. And not for inner nodes.

Comment: This works only the terminal nodes of the tree. The questions asks for non-terminal nodes.

Comment: @riccardo-df True that! I've adjusted the answer. I've left the answer anyway, b/c some users might need only terminal nodes and this involves only a limited amount of code. Higher-ranking answers provide a more thorough answer, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The `partykit` package also provides a canned solution for this. You just need to convert the `rpart` object to the `party` class in order to use its unified interface for dealing with trees. And then you can use the `data_party()` function.

Using the `fit` from the question and having loaded `library("partykit")` you can first coerce the `rpart` tree to `party`:

```
pfit <- as.party(fit)
plot(pfit)
```

[image: full pfit tree]

There are only two small nuisances for extracting the data in the way you want: (1) The `model.frame()` from the original fit is always dropped in the coercion and needs to be reattached manually. (2) A different numbering scheme is used for the nodes. You want node 4 (rather than 5) now.

```
pfit$data <- model.frame(fit)
data4 <- data_party(pfit, 4)
dim(data4)
## [1] 33  5
head(data4)
##    Kyphosis Age Start (fitted) (response)
## 2    absent 158    14        7     absent
## 10  present  59    12        8    present
## 11  present  82    14        8    present
## 14   absent   1    12        5     absent
## 18   absent 175    13        7     absent
## 20   absent  27     9        5     absent
```

Another route is to subset the subtree starting from node 4 and then taking the data from that:

```
pfit4 <- pfit[4]
plot(pfit4)
```

[image: subtree of pfit from node 4]

Then `data_party(pfit4)` gives you the same as `data4` above. And `pfit4$data` gives you the data without the `(fitted)` node and the predicted `(response)`.

Comment: if you used `ptree$data <- model.frame(eval(tree$call$data))` the variables not used in the formula wouldnt be dropped

Comment: True...but only if `data` contains all variables in the `formula` which is not necessarily the case. With the `model.frame()` you also get transformed variables, e.g., `log()`, `Surv()` or `factor()` versions of variables that are often created on the fly.

Comment: BTW: The `as.party()` coercion for `rpart` objects now _keeps the data_ by default! Thus, you can do `as.party(fit, data = TRUE)` (which is the new default) or `as.party(fit, data = FALSE)` (which corresponds to the old behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way, this works by finding all of the terminal nodes of any particular node and returning the subset of data used in the call.

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start, data = kyphosis)

head(subset.rpart(fit, 5))
#    Kyphosis Age Number Start
# 2    absent 158      3    14
# 10  present  59      6    12
# 11  present  82      5    14
# 14   absent   1      4    12
# 18   absent 175      5    13
# 20   absent  27      4     9


subset.rpart <- function(tree, node = 1L) {
  data <- eval(tree$call$data, parent.frame(1L))
  wh <- sapply(as.integer(rownames(tree$frame)), parent)
  wh <- unique(unlist(wh[sapply(wh, function(x) node %in% x)]))
  data[rownames(tree$frame)[tree$where] %in% wh[wh >= node], ]
}

parent <- function(x) {
  if (x[1] != 1)
    c(Recall(if (x %% 2 == 0L) x / 2 else (x - 1) / 2), x) else x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rpart returns rpart.object element which contains the information you need:

```
require(rpart)
fit2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit2

get_node_date <-function(nodeId,fit)
{  
  fit$frame[toString(nodeId),"n"]
}


for (i in c(1,2,4,5,10,11,22,23,3) )
  cat(get_node_date(i,fit2),"\n")
```

Comment: You don't get the observations through this, but only the number of abservations which fall into a category

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method consists in finding all children nodes from the given node `n`.
We can use the `rpart` object to find those. Combining this information with the
end node for each point in the dataset (kyphosis, in this question),
obtained from `fit$where` as explained
@rawar, you can get all points in the dataset involved in given node, not
necessarily an end one.

A summary of the steps are:

1. Find node numbers and identify those that are end nodes ("leaf"). This
   information can be found in the `frame` element of the rpart object.
2. Compute all children nodes of the given node `n`. They can be computed
   recursively using the fact that the children of node `n` are `2*n` and
   `2*n+1`, as explained in the `rpart.plot` package
   [vignette](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf) page 26
3. Once the leaves hanging from the node `n` are known, pick the points in the
   dataset in those leaves using the `where` element of the rpart object

I coded steps 1 and 2 in function `get_children_nodes()` and step 3 in function
`get_node_data()` that answers the question posed. In this function, i've
included the possibility to print the corresponding node rule (`rule = TRUE`) to
get the same answer than @datamineR

```r
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Start, data = kyphosis)
```

```r
get_children_nodes <- function(tree, node){
  # check if node is a leaf based in rpart object (tree) information (step 1)
  z <- tree$frame
  is_leaf <- z$var == "<leaf>"
  nodes <- as.integer(row.names(z))
  
  # find recursively all children nodes (step 2)
  find_children <- function(node, nodes, is_leaf){
    condition <- is_leaf[nodes == node]
    if (condition) {
      # If node is leaf, return it
      v1 <- node
    } else {
      # If node is not leaf, search children leaf recursively
      v1 <- c(find_children(2 * node, nodes, is_leaf), 
              find_children(2 * node + 1, nodes, is_leaf))
    } 
    return(v1)
  }
  
  return(find_children(node, nodes, is_leaf))
}
```

```r
get_node_data <- function(dataset, tree, node, rule = FALSE) {
  # Find children nodes of the node
  children_nodes <- get_children_nodes(tree, node)
  # match those nodes into the rpart node identification
  id_nodes <- which(as.integer(row.names(tree$frame)) %in% children_nodes)
  # Get the elements in the datset involved in the node (step 3)
  filtered_dataset <- dataset[tree$where %in% id_nodes, ]
  
  # print the node rule if needed
  if(rule) {
    rpart::path.rpart(tree, node, pretty = TRUE)
    cat("  \n")
  }
  return( filtered_dataset)
}
```

```r
# Get the children nodes
get_children_nodes(fit, 5)
#> [1] 10 22 23
```

```r
# Complete function to return the elements of node 5
get_node_data(kyphosis, fit, 5, rule = TRUE) 
#> 
#>  node number: 5 
#>    root
#>    Start>=8.5
#>    Start< 14.5
#> 
#>    Kyphosis Age Number Start
#> 2    absent 158      3    14
#> 10  present  59      6    12
#> 11  present  82      5    14
#> 14   absent   1      4    12
#> 18   absent 175      5    13
#> 20   absent  27      4     9
#> 23  present  96      3    12
#> 26   absent   9      5    13
#> 28   absent 100      3    14
#> 32   absent 125      2    11
#> 33   absent 130      5    13
#> 35   absent 140      5    11
#> 37   absent   1      3     9
#> 39   absent  20      6     9
#> 40  present  91      5    12
#> 42   absent  35      3    13
#> 46  present 139      3    10
#> 48   absent 131      5    13
#> 50   absent 177      2    14
#> 51   absent  68      5    10
#> 57   absent   2      3    13
#> 59   absent  51      7     9
#> 60   absent 102      3    13
#> 66   absent  17      4    10
#> 68   absent 159      4    13
#> 69   absent  18      4    11
#> 71   absent 158      5    14
#> 72   absent 127      4    12
#> 74   absent 206      4    10
#> 77  present 157      3    13
#> 78   absent  26      7    13
#> 79   absent 120      2    13
#> 81   absent  36      4    13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>