# Adding informations to tree - Rpart

Tags: r, tree, rpart, cart-analysis

I want to add some information to my tree. Let's say for instance I have a database like this :

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
set.seed(1)
mydb<-data.frame(results=rnorm(1000,0,1),expo=runif(1000),var1=sample(LETTERS[1:4],1000,replace=T),
                 var2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],1000,replace=T),var3=sample(LETTERS[20:25], 1000,replace=T))
```

I can run a tree :

```
mytree<-rpart(results~var1+var2+var3,data=mydb,cp=0)
pfit<- prune(mytree, cp=mytree$cptable[4,"CP"])
prp(pfit,type=1,extra=100,fallen.leaves=F,shadow.col="darkgray",box.col=rgb(0.8,0.9,0.8))
```

The result looks like this :
[image]

And it's ok for me, but let's imagine I want to know the average exposure for each leaf.

I know i can add some informations to prp, for instance the weight of each leaf with a function :

```
node.fun1 <- function(x, labs, digits, varlen)
{
  paste("Weight \n",x$frame$wt)
}

prp(pfit,type=1,extra=100,fallen.leaves=F,shadow.col="darkgray",box.col=rgb(0.8,0.9,0.8),node.fun = node.fun1)
```

[image]

But it works only if it's calculated in frame, the results of the rpart function.

## My question :

How can I add custom informations to the plot, like the average exposure, or any other function that calculates custom indicators and add it to the table `frame` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really nice, I didn't know this was an option.

All the work seems to be getting the subset of the original data used on each node. This is easy for terminal nodes, but I didn't find a straight-forward way of identifying rows of data that were used in every node, not just the leaves. If someone knows an easier way, I would love to hear it.

```
library('rpart.plot')
set.seed(1)
mydb<-data.frame(results=rnorm(1000,0,1),expo=runif(1000),var1=sample(LETTERS[1:4],1000,replace=T),
                 var2=sample(LETTERS[5:6],1000,replace=T),var3=sample(LETTERS[20:25], 1000,replace=T))
mytree<-rpart(results~var1+var2+var3,data=mydb,cp=0)
pfit<- prune(mytree, cp=mytree$cptable[4,"CP"])

rpart.plot(pfit)
```

[image]

Define your new function which takes `x`, the result of fitting `rpart` (I didn't look into the other arguments, but the vignette should be helpful).

For every line of `x$frame` we need to get the data used to calculate summary statistics. Unfortunately, `x$where` only tells us the terminal node in which each observation lies. So for each node number, we use `subset.rpart` to get the underlying data, and do whatever you want with it

```
f <- function(x, labs, digits, varlen) {
  nodes <- as.integer(rownames(x$frame))
  z <- sapply(nodes, function(y) {
    data <- subset.rpart(x, y)
    c(mean = mean(data$expo), nrow(data), nrow(data) / length(x$where) * 100)
  })
  sprintf('Mean expo: %.2f\nn=%.0f (%.0f%%)', z[1, ], z[2, ], z[3, ])
}

prp(pfit, type=1, extra=100, fallen.leaves=FALSE,
    shadow.col="darkgray", box.col=rgb(0.8,0.9,0.8),
    node.fun = f)
```

[image]

The work was done by `subset.rpart` which takes a node number and returns the subset of `data` used on the node.

```
subset.rpart <- function(tree, node = 1L) {
  ## returns subset of tree$call$data used on any node
  data <- eval(tree$call$data, parent.frame(1L))
  wh <- sapply(as.integer(rownames(tree$frame)), parent)
  wh <- unique(unlist(wh[sapply(wh, function(x) node %in% x)]))
  data[rownames(tree$frame)[tree$where] %in% wh[wh >= node], ]
}

parent <- function(x) {
  ## returns vector of parent nodes
  if (x[1] != 1)
    c(Recall(if (x %% 2 == 0L) x / 2 else (x - 1) / 2), x) else x
}
```

Tests

```
## tests
dim(subset.rpart(pfit, 1)) == dim(mydb)
# [1] TRUE TRUE

## terminal nodes
nodes <- as.integer(rownames(pfit$frame[pfit$frame$var %in% '<leaf>', ]))
sum(sapply(nodes, function(x) nrow(subset.rpart(pfit, x)))) == nrow(mydb)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect ! Did you code yourself subset.rpart & parent ? That's something else I was looking for

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I found [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748531/getting-the-observations-in-a-rparts-node-i-e-cart) a little too late. you might find an alternative there you like better

Comment: Actually I prefer your version, your code is really nice and easy to read, thanks again for all your work

Comment: happy to help, this was something I've wanted/needed to do but never got around to it