# rpart: How to get the "where" vector for validation dataset?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

when fitting with rpart, it returns the "where" vector which tells which leave each record in the training dataset is on the tree. Is there a function which return something similar to this "where" vector for a test dataset?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, you want to get the subset for any node? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748531/getting-the-observations-in-a-rparts-node-i-e-cart

Comment: Just something similar to the rpart$where vector of numbers, which tells which leave a record is on. But this is only for the training data. I wonder if I can get something similar for a test dataset. The predict function doesn't seem to do this, it only gives predicted values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `partykit` package does what you want

```
library('rpart')
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit
rpart.plot::rpart.plot(fit)
```

[image]

Check with same data

```
set.seed(1)
idx <- sample(nrow(kyphosis), 5L)
fit$where[idx]
# 22 30 46 71 16 
#  9  3  7  7  3 

library('partykit')
fit <- as.party(fit)
predict(fit, kyphosis[idx, ], type = 'node')
# 22 30 46 71 16 
#  9  3  7  7  3
```

Check with new data

```
dd <- kyphosis[idx, ]
set.seed(1)
dd[] <- lapply(dd, sample)
predict(fit, dd, type = 'node')
# 22 30 46 71 16 
#  5  3  7  9  3 

## so #46 should meet criteria for the 7th leaf:
with(kyphosis[46, ],
     Start  >= 8.5  &  # node 1
       Start < 14.5 &  # node 2
       Age  >= 55   &  # node 4
       Age  >= 111     # node 6
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, but it seems the only accepted values for 'type' are  “vector”, “prob”, “class”, “matrix”

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the function `predict.rpart` in the `rpart` package
doesn't have a `where` option (to show the leaf node number associated
with a prediction).
However, the `rpart.predict` function in the `rpart.plot` package
will do this. For example

```
> library(rpart.plot)
> fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
> rpart.predict(fit, newdata=kyphosis[1:3,], nn=TRUE)
```

gives (note the node number `nn` column):

```
   absent present nn
1 0.42105 0.57895  3
2 0.85714 0.14286 22
3 0.42105 0.57895  3
```

And

```
> rpart.predict(fit, newdata=kyphosis[1:3,], nn=TRUE)$nn
```

gives just the `where` node numbers:

```
[1]  3 22  3
```

To show the rule for each prediction use

```
> rpart.predict(fit, newdata=kyphosis[1:5,], rules=TRUE)
```

which gives

```
   absent present
1 0.42105 0.57895 because Start <  9
2 0.85714 0.14286 because Start is 9 to 15 & Age >= 111
3 0.42105 0.57895 because Start <  9
```