# How to get index of observations in each node of a tree?

Tags: r, tree, cart

In R,

how do u retrieve for each node of a tree, the **index** of observations in each node in the tree, without recoding all the tree iterative procedure?

For example in *rpart* (an r package):

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis, cp = -1)
fit$splits
```

I would like to know for each splits, which observations go to the right node and which go to the left node.

Comment: Sorry, seems to be already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748531/getting-the-observations-in-a-rparts-node-i-e-cart?rq=1 . If someone wants to provide other links or methods (maybe faster methods for example), please feel free.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the observations in a rpart's node (i.e.: CART)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748531/getting-the-observations-in-a-rparts-node-i-e-cart)

Comment: It's working more or less. But a least now i know a way to code it. Thanks.